# SQL Server Management Studio Import/Export Data crashes on launch with "The data is invalid"

Tags: ssms

The SSMS Import/Export Data wizard no longer opens on my PC; it immediately crashes with the error below. I've tried launching it from with in SSMS via the context menu items "Import Data..." and "Export Data..." as well as the `DTSWizard.exe` file itself in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSIS\150\Binn`.

I've been using SSMS 18.9.2 since it was released and never had this problem, it just started today. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling SSMS 18.9.2 but no luck. Any ideas?

```
===================================

This wizard will close because it encountered the following error: (Microsoft SQL Server)

------------------------------
For help, click: https://go.microsoft.com:80/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=15.0.2000.168&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardFrameworkErrorSR&EvtID=UncaughtException&LinkId=20476

===================================

The data is invalid.


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.get_DBProviderInfos()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DTSWizard.GetDtsDbProviderInfos(WizardInputs wizardInputs)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.DataSourceCombo.PopulateProviders(Boolean fSources, WizardInputs wizardInputs)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.DtsWizard.Step1.OnInitializePage(EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardPage.RaiseEnterPage()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.NextPage(WizardPage nextPage)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.UI.WizardForm.Next_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
```

**Update**

Just now noticed that I can't add or edit steps in SQL Server Agent jobs. As soon as I click New or Edit in the Job Properties dialog I get a similar "The data is invalid" error:

```
===================================

The data is invalid.


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.get_LogProviderInfos()
   at Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.DTSExecUI.Controls.LoggingCtrl..ctor(IDTSExecViewManager treePanel)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DTSJobSubSystemDefinition.InitializeControls()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.DTSJobSubSystemDefinition..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems.CreateJobStepSubSystemSsis(AgentSubSystem agentSubSystem, CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems.CreateJobStepSubSystem(AgentSubSystem agentSubSystem, CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepSubSystems..ctor(CDataContainer dataContainer, JobStepData data, IMessageBoxProvider messageProvider, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.get_SubSystems()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.FilterStepCombo(DatabaseEngineEdition engineEdition)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.InitializeStepCombo()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.InitializeData()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobStepProperties.OnInitialization()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.SetView(Int32 index, TreeNode node)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.SelectCurrentNode()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.InitializeUI(ViewSwitcherTreeView treeView, ISqlControlCollection viewsHolder, Panel rightPane)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm.InitializeForm(XmlDocument doc, IServiceProvider provider, ISqlControlCollection control)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.LaunchForm..ctor(ISqlControlCollection control, IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.JobSteps.editJobStep_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
   at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Application.RunDialog(Form form)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog(IWin32Window owner)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Form.ShowDialog()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.RunningFormsTable.RunningFormsTableImpl.ThreadStarter.StartThread()

===================================

The data is invalid.


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper.ApplicationClass.get_LogProviderInfos()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application.get_LogProviderInfos()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally figured it out. A few days before this started I was messing with Winaero Tweaker, and followed the instructions [here](https://winaero.com/remove-share-with-skype-from-context-menu-in-windows-10/) to remove the "Share with Skype" item from Explorer's context menu. I undid that change to the registry key and DTSWizard.exe works again.

These are the steps from the Winaero site that broke it:

- Go to the following Registry key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\PackagedCom\ClassIndex{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}.
- On the left, right-click on the {776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8} folder, and select Rename from the context menu.Rename Key Comand In Regsitry
- Specify -{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8} as the new key name. (just add the minus sign to the folder name).

Comment: Thankyou!! I would never have figured this out - I don't use the Export Data that often, and disabled the Skype thing ages ago.
For me, the registry key had re-added itself, but the one I'd renamed was still there with its minus sign. I deleted it (they were otherwise identical), and all was good with SQL Server again.

Comment: Like @cometfish I had to remove the key with the dash in front of the name to fix the problem. Not adding it.

Comment: Deleting the `-{776DBC8D-7347-478C-8D71-791E12EF49D8}` registry key worked for me as well.

Comment: Also fixed SSMS Agent Job Step Edit.